# Preprocessing C code to only use C23 attribute notation

Tags: c, gcc, attributes, clang, c-preprocessor

Is there a way for GCC/Clang/a C pretty-printer tool to preprocess/pretty-print a source file, using only the "new" (C23) attribute notation? In other words, transform this code:

```c
int a __attribute__((foo));
```

Into this?

```c
int a[[foo]];
```

This would help for instance code analysis tools to avoid having to deal with both notations; code using non-standard GNU attribute notation could automatically become C23-compatible.

Comment: Seems like and half-decent text editor would be able to find & replace just fine, without knowing anything about the language. However, gcc has a metric tonne of various function attributes and C23 has a select few.

Comment: You could write a Perl or Python script to do the job.  Using a text editor would be more fiddly; and probably harder to automate.  The script would probably need to be aware of comments and strings, though you could simply ignore such refinements, certainly in a first pass.

Comment: `sed 's/__attribute__((\(.*\)))/[[\1]]/g'` could be enough for most cases